# Can one state appear in multiple state machine with AASM?

Tags: state-machine, aasm

Gem AASM supports [multiple state machine per class](https://github.com/aasm/aasm#multiple-state-machines-per-class) with verion 4.3 or above. A unique state machine selector is used for each state machine in one class. Can one state appear in multiple state machine?

Here is an example. The state `walking` appears in both `:move` and `:work`. Is `state walking` all right? Or I have to name differently like: `state walking_move` and `state waling_work`.

```
class SimpleMultipleExample
  include AASM
  aasm(:move) do
    state :standing, :initial => true
    state :walking  #<====

    event :walk do
      transitions :from => :standing, :to => :walking
    end
  end

  aasm(:work) do
    state :sleeping, :initial => true
    state :walking  #<====

    event :start do
      transitions :from => :sleeping, :to => :walking
    end
  end
end
```

Also can all initial state be the same such as `initial_state` in different state machine?

Comment: If you run this it gives a warning. `WARN -- : SimpleMultipleExample: overriding method 'walking?'!`. I'm not sure why you would want several state machines sharing a state in the same class?

Comment: The warning is ONLY for event. There is no mention for same state which is the question here.